# How can val() return Number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, numbers

In the `val`[docs](http://api.jquery.com/val/) written  this description:

> .val() Returns: String, Number, Array

I tried to get a `Number`, but it seems to return `string` only, Is there something that I'm doing wrong?

```js
$('#gdoron').val('1');

alert($('#gdoron').val() === '1'); // true 
alert(typeof $('#gdoron').val());  // string.

$('#gdoron').val(1);

alert($('#gdoron').val() === 1);  // false
alert(typeof $('#gdoron').val()); // string (not "number"!)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="gdoron" />
```

My question is: **how can `val()` return number as the docs says?** The question is not about how can I parse the string.

​

Comment: A new, similar, question has been asked, but this question doesn't have the answer:  use `valHooks`.  That answer should probably be here, but this is a very old question, so answered it there...   https://stackoverflow.com/a/70143214/2181514

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Some HTML5 elements e.g. progress;

```js
console.log(typeof $("#prog").val()); // number
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<progress value="50" max="100" id="prog"></progress>
```

Comment: Also see the [HTML5 draft](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#the-progress-element) (the return value is `double`).

Comment: @gdoron: It says:  *[...] form elements **such as** `input`, `select` and `textarea` [...]*. Now, I'm not a native English speaker, but it sounds to me that this is not meant to be an exhaustive list.

Comment: Something weird: `alert($("#prog").val() === 50​)​;​​​​​​​​​​//false​​` and `alert($("#prog").val() === '50')​; //false​​​​​​​​​​​​`. **HOW?**

Answer (score 71):

A text input's `value` attribute will always return a string. You need to `parseInt` the value to get an integer:

```
parseInt($('#myInput').val(), 10);
```

Comment: I know that, I'm asking how can `val` return number as the docs says, not how can I parse the string.

Comment: Using the unary operators `-`, `+` and `~` before the `$` will also return a ***number***. 


 `+$('#gdoron').val();`

Comment: Can someone explain what the parameter 10 does in this function ?

Comment: @AntoinePelletier it's a radix (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#syntax)

Answer (score 16):

I've done a bit of quick peeking around, and I think I have an answer. If you look at the implementation of the [`val` function](http://jsapi.info/jquery/1.7/jQuery.fn.val) you can see that if a so-called val-hook is in place, if the val-hook returns a number, that number will be returned as-is from the val function. I found [this discussion](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/valhooks-discussion-pros-cons) which suggests that val-hooks are primarily used by plugins to create custom controls, such as sliders, etc., where the "natural" return value of `val` could be an integer. Hope this sheds a bit of light on your question.

Comment: It looks like it returns a number by default. `$("<progress value='50' max='100'>").get(0).value === 50`.

Comment: The first link is broken.

Comment: Too many pending edits, so I have to post an updated first link as a comment: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/8be4c0e4f89d6c8f780e5937a0534921d8c7815e/src/attributes/val.js#L9

Answer (score 4):

Hmm. For all these in the console, jQuery `$($0).val()` and Javascript's `$0.value` return the string "3":

```
<input type='number' value='3'/>
<input type='text' value='3'/>
<input type='radio' value='3'/>
<input type='checkbox' value='3'/>
```

So I think [the jQuery val() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/val/) could be clearer. I can't see how it would ever return a number value so I'd suggest using `parseInt($($0).val())` or `parseFloat($($0).val())`.

Answer (score 3):

You could simply create a jquery plugin to use instead of val() that would do this. Here I create the function nval() to use instead of val() when fetching a elements value.

```
$.fn.nval = function() {
   return Number(this.val())
};
```

Then in your code just use the following to get the value as a number

```
$('#elementID').nval()
```

Comment: While correct, it doesn't answer the (very old) question.

Comment: Sure thats true but its provides a way to do it thats safe. If you really want to  do it just use a plugin that overrides val() like 

    $.fn._val = jq.fn.val;
    $.fn.val = function(value) {
        if ( !arguments.length ) {
            var v = this._val();
            if(!isNaN(+v)) {
                return Number(v);
            }
            return v;
        } else {
            return this._val(value);
        }
     };

Comment: Dude, the question is not how to overcome a problem, simply trying to understand how jQuery itself can return a `Number` **as the doc says**. And you can see the accepted answer showing why they wrote it, `<progress>` for example returns a `Number` **natively!**.