# Trouble using typeof operator in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeof

This will be the first time on SO I don't preface my question with, "I'm new to programming" (whoops).  I'll get right into it:

Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="hide" id="hide2">
    <div class="inputselect">   
    <p>
        <label>What is your budget?</label>
        </p>
        <p>
            Minimum: $<input type="text" id="minBud" name='minBud'><br />
            Maximum: $<input type="text" id="maxBud" name='maxBud'><br />
        <br />
        </p>
        <button type="button" class="next" id="next3">Next</button>
        <button type="button" class="prev" id="prev2">Previous</button> 
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery/javascript code snippet I'm struggling with:

```
$("#next3").click(function(){
    if (typeof $("#minBud").val() === "number" && typeof $("#maxBud").val() === "number") { 
        gunsPrice();
        $("#hide3").slideDown("fast");
        $("#hide2").slideUp("fast");
    } else {
        alert("Please only enter NUMBERS into the budget fields");
    }
});
```

What I'd like to see happen is: if the entries the the `minBud` and `maxBud` fields are numbers, run `gunsPrice()` and present the next question (HTML form).

I've tried altering the syntax several different ways, but no matter how I do it, numbers continue to trigger the `alert`.

*Note:* I can get the `typeof` operator to function correctly within `gunsPrice()` (using variables gathered with `getElementById`, but that doesn't do me any good within this application; it always moves to the next question (due to the way I've set up the jQuery code).

Thanks!

Comment: You should echo out typeof and see what the code thinks it is. Likely "string" since it came from a form element.

Comment: `val` always returns a string.  You need to parse it to validate that what the user entered is a valid number.

Comment: Post a jsfiddle with your code. In the meantime, console.log() the .val() of both inputs separately from your if/then. Verify what the typeof for each is.

Comment: according to the documentation val() can return number but the documentation fails to mention in what situation it will return a number. http://api.jquery.com/val/

Comment: I tried Cfreak's suggestion (not sure why I didn't think of that before...), and the variables are recognized as 'object'.  I'm assuming it's in bad taste to change my condition from "number" to "object" :)

Comment: Hey Geuis, I'm a little embarrassed, but I'm not sure what a jsfiddle is...I'll definitely look it up though.  Thanks for the tip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.val()` always return a string for inputs. so you condition will always evaluate to false. You can however check to see if the results only contain digits(if that's what you're looking for)

```
if (/^\d+$/.test($("#minBud").val()) && /^\d+$/.test($("#maxBud").val())) {
```

Comment: According to jQuery documentation val() can return number but then fails to mention when it would return a number http://api.jquery.com/val/ I gues the easiest way is to isNaN(parseFloat($("something").val()))

Comment: @HMR it does say that though I'm unable to get a result that wasn't a string(or array of string).

Comment: There is some [discussion here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227268/how-can-val-return-number).  `type=text` likely won't ever return a number, though.

Comment: @HMR It happens exactly when el.value gets you a number. That will happen, at least in chrome, for the HTML5 `<input type="number"/>`

Comment: @Musa I like the logic, but unfortunately it didn't work (same result as originally).

Comment: @Paulpro I've tried it but keeps returning string, checking $.valHooks the only objects there are: checkbox, option, radio and select. Maybe the html 5 isn't valid I do have <!DOCTYPE html> as the first line and input type='number'

Comment: @Musa Oh. I was mistaken. Thanks for making the jsfiddle to show me.

Comment: @RemoWilliams I had a mistake in my post try now

Comment: @Paulpro using jQuery 1.9.0 and adding a hook for number it still returns string until I add $.valHooks.text it finally returns number. Validated the document and it's html 5 no errors and the input IS type number. I guess in theory this should work but there is a bug in jQuery that prevents it from working correctly.

Comment: @Musa that did the trick.  Thanks!  I got this to work right after you posted your correction: `if (($("#minBud").val() * 0) === 0 && ($("#minBud").val() * 0) === 0) {`.  Yours, however, is cooler than mine :)

Comment: @Paulpro I see in the jQuery source it tries to get the type like so: elem.type but that returns "text" even though it's type is set to number. If I do elem.attributes.getNamedItem("type").value I get "number" This might be a bug in Firefox, have validated html as html 5. Can anyone confirm this? (this does not happen in Chrome)

Comment: @HMR Firefox hasn't implemented `input[type=number]` yet - the value of the type *attribute* is number, but the type *property* is still "text".

Comment: @Dennis thanks, just figured it out and ajusted my answer. I thought it was a bug in FireFox so my answer sugggest adding .getAttribut and add a data-type="number" attribute.

Comment: `.val()` may also return an array (for `select` elements with the `multiple` property) and, as per [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/val/) may also return a number (as shown in the already linked [discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227268/how-can-val-return-number)).

Comment: yes but you don't need to do anything to have jQuery return an array as it has $.valHooks.select.get If you'd like to have it return a number you have to add something to the $.valHooks.[someting].get yourself.

Comment: Yeah I'm just commenting as the first statement in this answer "`.val()` always return a string." may be true for this use case, but is not 100% accurate.

Answer (score 1):

I now see that you can add hooks in jQuery so .val() can return a number. You can hook into val() using the following code:

```
$.valHooks.text={
  get:function(elem){
    var i=parseFloat(elem.value,10);
    return (isNaN(i))?elem.value:i
  }
}
```

Now val() of any input type text will return a string or number depending if it can be converted.

This might be confusing though because the input type is TEXT.

You could use $valHooks.number and set the input of type number but tried this in Firefox 20.0.1 and didn't work.

This because jQuery tries to get the hook using

```
jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ]
```

Since FireFox will return "text" when asking for an elem.type of type "number" it'll not call your hook and return the elem.value property wich is string. This is probably a bug in FireFox as

```
elem.getAttribute("type")
```

returns "number"

A way to overcome this bug is to go into jQuery source code and change the following line:

```
hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ] || jQuery.valHooks[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ];
```

to

```
hooks = jQuery.valHooks[ elem.type ] || jQuery.valHooks[ elem.nodeName.toLowerCase() ]
  || jQuery.valHooks[ elem.getAttribute("data-type") ];
```

Now in your html you can specify a number input field by:

```
<input type="number" data-type="number" ...
```

And add a nubmer hook:

```
$.valHooks.number={...//see code above for the rest
```

Comment: I sincerely appreciate the explanation.  Thank you

Comment: I guess hooks is a good way to implement type conversion as it centralises conversion. Too bad FireFox is not playing along and too bad the jQuery code does not support setting hooks for other attributes (except node name and node.type). Just added this for completion and future reference.

Answer (score 0):

In `$("#minBud").val()`, `#minBud` is an input or textarea.

Your operation:

```
typeof $("#minBud").val()
```

is a "String".

```
parseInt($("#minBud").val(),10) === null
```

Comment: Where exactly in the documentation say it will return a string when getting .val() from a textbox? http://api.jquery.com/val/ it says clearly it can return number but just doesn't say in what situation.

Comment: `parseInt` will return `NaN` if an integer cannot be parsed, not `null`