# Get int value from a textfield

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

This might be a very simple quesion. But I simply haven't been able to find the answer googling around.

I was wondering if there was a way that I could get the int value of a textfield instead of just the value.

Html:

```
<input id="Price" type="number" value="" placeholder="Price" />
```

JavaScript:

```
var oCar = 
{
    "Price": $('#Price').val()
}
```

Let's fx. say that I then add a speed property to the car. And later, I would then like to call it in an animate function like = "oCar.Speed".

```
$(".Car").animate({
//some animation
}, oCar.Speed, function() {

});
```

Then it's wouldn't work since the speed would be a string.

Comment: I just skimmed your question, but are you looking for `parseInt(...,10)` or `parseFloat(...)`?

Comment: Can't you just parseInt() the value ?

Comment: Either that or prefix the string with `+`.

Comment: `parseInt("10"); // 10 -> int`

Comment: https://www.google.se/search?q=jquery+value+to+int&oq=jquery+value+to+int&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2191j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=jquery+val+to+int

Comment: @ubercooluk, don't forget the radix.

Comment: Refer:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227268/how-can-val-return-number

Comment: @BlazingCoder That's a question about why `val()` sometimes returns `number` instead of `string`...

Comment: @Archer `"10" + 2` gives `"102"`

Comment: @PaulS. Oh yeah, of course it does.  Silly me :D  Why do they let it work with the other common operators then?  Just stop it working for all of them to avoid confusion.

Comment: @Archer this is because _String_ operators will shadow _Number_ operators (in _JavaScript_). String has no such operator `*`, `-` or `/` so it's only `+` you will see this happen with.

Comment: @PaulS That's exactly my point.  Concatenation obviously makes perfect sense, but allowing the other 3 operators to work is just crazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
$(".Car").animate({
//some animation
}, parseInt(oCar.Speed,10), function() {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

All *HTMLInputElements* will have a *String* for *value*, you could try using *valueAsNumber*, but I would not rely on this for now for compatibility reasons. Instead, cast the *String* to *Number* in your favourite way. For example; using a [bitwise *OR*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.7C_%28Bitwise_OR%29) *`0`* to call *JavaScript's* internal [*ToInt32*](http://es5.github.io/#x9.5) (as [described in the spec](http://es5.github.io/#x11.10)).

```
var oCar = {
    "Price": $('#Price').val() | 0
};
```