# Adding 1 to an input field

Tags: jquery

I can't figure out why this wont work. I'm trying to get a simple counter working. When a user clicks "yes" I want to increase the value of a hidden text box  by 1. Currently, when I click yes, the text box's value changes to "102" and the appended text shows as "101102". Any ideas?

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
var yesValue  = parseInt($("#trend-one-yes").val());
$("#trend-one-yes").val(yesValue+1);

var $addDiv = $('#yes');
$addDiv.append($("#trend-one-yes").val());
```

---

#### Update

I added some of the suggested code. It's still outputting the wrong number. It should be increasing by 1 instead its going up by 2. Thanks for your help!

```
<div id="vote" class="animated" data-fx="slideInDown">   
  <div class="vote-w">
  <div class="vbut" id="yes"><div>&#xe0fe;</div><div class="tag">Yes</div></div>
  <div class="vbut" id="no"><div>&#xe0fd;</div><div class="tag">No</div></div>
</div>
                    
<div  id="results">
  <div class="res" id="yesNum"></div>
  <div class="res" id="noNum"></div>                    
  <form id="vals" method="post" action="data/save.php" target="sub">
    <input id="trend-one-yes" name="trend-one-yes" 
           value="<?php echo $survey->one->yes?>"/>
    <input id="trend-one-no" name="trend-one-no" 
           value="<?php echo $survey->one->no?>"/>                    
  </form>
  <iframe id="sub" frameborder="0" name="sub" 
          style="height:1px; width:1px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

And the script

```
<script>
  $("#yes").mouseup(function()
    {
      $(this).css("color","#ffffff");
      $('#results').slideDown({ duration: 1000, easing: "easeOutBounce" });
      var $tyes = $("#trend-one-yes");
      var count = parseInt($tyes.val(), 10) + 1
      $tyes.val(count);
      var $addDiv = $('#yesNum').text(count);
      $( "#vals" ).submit();
    });
</script>
```

---

Tried the code added below. Thanks again, but its still adding 2 instead of one. How can that be?

Comment: show the html structure

Comment: What is the initial value? try $addDiv.html(...);

Comment: can you share more code/fiddle so we can help you?

Comment: Have you considered to fork one of my codepen examples to demonstrate what you mean? Could you update the description of what is not working and [please update the user action, the problem and the expected result](http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/sample-bug-report/) Example: Expected: On clicking on `<div id="yes">` the counter for trend yes should increase by one. 
Problem: On clicking ...
Steps to reproduce: ....

Answer (score 1):

Instead of updating the `#yes` element with new value, you are appending the new value to the existing one. Use .html() to replace the existing value with new one

```
var $tyes = $("#trend-one-yes");
var count = parseInt($tyes.val(), 10) + 1
$tyes.val(count);

var $addDiv = $('#yes').text(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to **replace** the node value not **append**

```
$addDiv.html($("#trend-one-yes").val());
```

Answer (score 0):

Recap of questions

1. Given a form-field value of 101 how do i increase it by one after clicking on an element?
2. why does my code sets the value to `101102` instead of changing the value to `102`?
3. why does my updated code increase the value by 2 instead of increasing it by 1?

**Question 1** you have to make sure that the value you get is of type `number` 
If you take a look at the [jQuery docs for val](http://api.jquery.com/val/) you can see that val returns a String or a Number or an Array. So you have to make sure that you turn it into a number. 
To get the number of clicks you can use parseint [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kc6b02f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) .

```
// get the value from <input id=trend-one-yes type=??? <-- i assume type=text?
var yesCount = parseint($("#trend-one-yes").val(), 10); 
// increase value by 1 and write it back into the field
yesCount = yesCount  +1;
$("#trend-one-yes").val(yesCount);
```

**Question 2** was because you used jQuery [`append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) instead of [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/). 
The question  [How do I add an integer value with javascript (jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227268/how-can-val-return-number) has additional information.

```
var $addDiv = $('#yes'); // get a reference to <div id=yes>
// append is the wrong function --> $addDiv.append($("#trend-one-yes").val());

// the newYesCount will be increased by one after a certain user action
var newYesCount = GetNewYesCount(yesCount);
$addDiv.val(newYesCount);
```

#### Update 3 for Question 3

To be able to help i need more information. I believe that you want this:

- the initial value for yesCount is 101 and comes from `<input id="trend-one-yes"`
- after user clicks on `<div id="yes">` the value yesCount (101) is increased by 1
- and the new value (101+1=102) is written into `<div id="yesNum">`

Your code shows that for `<div id=yes` a mouseup event is attached:

```
$("#yes").mouseup(function()
{
   // i assume get yes count from <input id="trend-one-yes
   var yesCount = GetCurrentYesCount();
   // increase yesCount by 1 after a certain user action
   var newYesCount = GetNewYesCount(yesCount);
   // write newYesCount into another form field
   // i assume <div class="res" id="yesNum">
});
```

The following could be reasons for your trouble

- the elements are mixed up
- mouseup fires twice because of [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html)
- It could be that several event listeners are attached and your function mouseup fires twice or another function that increases by 1 fires. 
  Check out **[how to see which event listeners are bound to an element](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/buorh)**
- Or it could be that you would like to increase by 1 only if a checkbox is checked. This means increase only by 1 if a checkbox was selected.

#### Help us to help you

If you could fork

- either **[my third codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hHJsc)**
- or [my 4th. codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Ckafn)

so that it shows your use case i could help.

Comment: Yes, this is the only instance of $("#yes"). Still adding by two. I added a new button with a completely different #, still not working. Thx

Comment: @user2750623: I do not mean the only instance. I was talking about how many [event listeners a registered for the elements](http://infoheap.com/use-chrome-developer-tools-to-view-event-handlers/)  `id=yes` and may be even for `id=vote`

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Turns up it was a conflict with the fullPage.js plugin I was using. Without it everything works fine. Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Would you mind upvoting or in case you can not do that accepting my answer since it adresses a few issues of your post?

How did you found out that it was the fullPage.js plugin - did you look at the event listeners?