# Why does attribute value of input = text, but attribute value of li = number?

Tags: javascript, jquery, attributes, typeof

http://jsfiddle.net/3GTtF/2/

```
<ul>
    <li class="first" value="45">fortyfive</li>
    <li class="second" value="4text5">45</li>
</ul>

<input value="45">
```

---

```
var whatIsValue = $('.first').val();            //  = 45     typeof = number
var whatIsSecondValue = $('.second').val();     //  = 4      typeof = number
var whatIsInputValue = $('input').val();        //  = '45'   typeof = string
```

Why does `var whatIsSecondValue = 4` instead of `'4text5'`

Why does `var whatIsInputValue = '45'` instead of `45`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can val() return Number?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227268/how-can-val-return-number)

Comment: It's strange than val() works on LI.

Comment: I see in jQuery source for valHooks method, returning elem.text PS: after testing seems not to be that!   `jQuery.find.attr( $('.first')[0], "value" )` returning correct value as we should expect it :(

Comment: Wait, for me $('.first').val(); returns fortyfive, not for you?! That's was the purpose of my previous comment. {tested on chrome}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the WHY i'm not sure but a `li` tag shouldn't have a `value` attribute. You should use data-* attribute instead. It is invalid/improper HTML syntax.

As shown below

```
<ul>
    <li class="first" data-value="45">fortyfive</li>
    <li class="second" data-value="4text5">45</li>
</ul>


var whatIsValue = $('.first').data('value');
var whatIsSecondValue = $('.second').data('value'); // = 4text5 typeof = string
var whatIsInputValue = $('input').val();
```

### Update

Apparently in HTML5 once can use a value attribute, see comments below. In that case to solve this you could use the .prop() or .attr() methods.

### Another Update

Because in HTML5 the value attribute on a `li` is of type integer/number by default. As to why it trims the string to 4, that's a mystery.

[image]

Comment: true, value is not valid attribute for LI inside UL but doesn't explain this behaviour

Comment: I agree...you're using .val() in an unintended context...not surprising you're getting strange results

Comment: Actually in HTML5, `<li>` tags *can* have a `value`: http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/li.html

Comment: @RocketHazmat "The ordinal value of the list item. Permitted only if the li element is a child of an **ol** element." Here it is an UL ;)

Comment: @RocketHazmat From here http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_li.asp "Specifies the value of a list item. The following list items will increment from that number (only for <ol> lists)"  I think that means you can use value for any li, whether inside UL or OL , they just won't increment if you use UL. ?

Comment: @AlienArrays: `<ul>`'s don't have an "order".  That's what "ul" stands for "unordered list".  So, `value` doesn't mean anything for a `<ul>`.

Comment: @AlienArrays W3fool is quite confusing on it, that's correct. Sorry i mean http://www.w3fools.com/

Answer (score 2):

If you're gonna use `.val()` incorrectly, you'll get strange results.

If you're set on using `value=""` in an `li`, to access it you must use `.attr("value")`

see the updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3GTtF/3/

Comment: @AlienArrays but we are talking about UL, not OL. Value attribute is still not valid or i'm missing something?!

Comment: You can set any attribute you want, it will still be parsed but doesn't mean it is 'valid' attribute

Answer (score 1):

when you do `parseInt('4text5')` it also returns 4 because that's how this function works.
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

I guess jqueries val() method is using parseInt somewhere but I'm not sure. It sure is something similar.

Also it make sense that the value of a list is an integer and the value of an input field (type text) is a string. isn't it?

javascript/jquery probably doesn't check the type you actually put in the field. If you want a number from an input field you need to set the type to number `<input type="number">` thats why there are that many "meaningful" html elements. javascript expects that you use these elements for what they are designed for.

The way the value is extracted (as string, number, date etc) is depended on the HTML (or other markup language).

So the more I think about it the more it makes sense that the .val() method is returning a particular "type" depending on the dom element type.

- li -> default value is integer (it is a list with a defined number of li elements so it would be odd/strange that it would be a string)
- input[text] -> string
- input[number] -> integer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the getAttribute method:
http://jsfiddle.net/chace/t2HCH/61/

```
var new1Txt = $(".first").text();
var new1Val = $(".first").val();
var new2Txt = $(".second").text();
var new2Val = $(".second").val();
var new2Real = x = document.getElementsByClassName("second");
var new2JQ = $(".second");

$(document).ready(function () {

    $(".container").append("<p>" + new1Txt + "</p>");
    $(".container").append("<p>" + new1Val + "</p>");
    $(".container").append("<p>" + new2Txt + "</p>");
    $(".container").append("<p>" + new2Val + "</p>");
    $(".container").append("<p>" + new2Real[0].getAttribute('value') + "</p>");
    $(".container").append("<p>" + new2JQ[0].getAttribute('value') + "</p>");

});
```