# Comparing two integer values showing strange results

Tags: javascript, html

I just came across a strange situation while comparing two `integer` values. One value is read from `Database` and its type is `int` so this is an `int` value. Second value comes from a `textbox` whose type is `number`.

If `textbox` value is less than 100 than comparison is fine if it is greater than 100 comparison shows strange results.

If i use `parseInt` than everything is fine. I just want to know why this is happening ?

```
var CADMeterReading = 10;
<input type="number" name="MeterReading" placeholder="0000" value="20" id="MeterReading"   />

if($("#MeterReading").val()) <= CADMeterReading) //returns false as excepted
```

If textbox has value greater than 100 than it is not comparing as expected

```
var CADMeterReading = 80;
<input type="number" name="MeterReading" placeholder="0000" value="100" id="MeterReading"   />

if($("#MeterReading").val()) <= CADMeterReading) //returns true
```

Comment: input's `value` attribute will always return a string. You need to use `parseInt`.

Comment: `"100" <= 80` **does not** return true. http://jsfiddle.net/13no19dz/

Answer (score 4):

Defining the type of the `input` as `number` only stops the use from entering anything else than numbers:

```
<input type="number" name="MeterReading" placeholder="0000" value="20" id="MeterReading"/>
```

But that does **not** means that javascript will read it as a *number*.

`$("#MeterReading").val()` will return the data as `String` type, and hence you are comparing a string and an integer, which results in *strange* comparison.

That is also why when you use `parseInt`, the numbers are compared properly, since you have now asked javascript to convert the `string` to `integer` before comparing.

Comment: But why this works fine for values less than 100 ?

Comment: That is probably because the ASCII value of the _character_ you entered is less than the _integer_ you are comparing it to, which results in giving you the 'seemingly' correct comparison result.

Comment: Hi Its still working without parseInt. Mairaj in your code you kept an extra ')'   in condition. may be that would be an issue..

    **Demo link :** http://jsfiddle.net/asimshahiddIT/8s3vd59r

Comment: Actually, the comparison will work as-is without `parseInt` (etc) as long as one operand is not-a-string.

Answer (score 1):

An input element will always return a string, this is just how `jQuery.val()` works, and I think to a large degree takes it's lead from the HTML spec (which defines the return value of `inputElement.value` as type `DOMString`).

See more discussion of this here: [How can val() return Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227268/how-can-val-return-number) , but essentially it sounds like you've found the answer already in terms of functionality - use `parseInt($("#MeterReading").val(),10)`

Comment: I just want to know why this works for values less than 100 and not for greater than 100.

Comment: It's performing a string comparsion

Answer (score 0):

Defining number, doesn't mean that it provides value in integer, it always gives you as string
So you need to use parseInt() to convert it into integer for compare number

> Its string comparison, try "100" < 101, this give you true So don't
>   take it like it not works with above 100