# typeof command doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeof

Hi I'm trying to check the value of DOM with:

```
if ($('#ATTN').val() == '') {               
    $('#ATTN').val(0);
} else {
    iattn=$('#ATTN').val();
    alert(iattn);

    if(typeof iattn == 'number'){
        alert('oh');
    }
}
```

but it returns nothing. Also no error shown.

Comment: Have you opened your debugger and seen what `typeof iattn` equals exactly?

Comment: Seems like `typeof iattn` would be a string if you got it from an input type text.

Comment: $('#ATTN').val() - return string, not number.

Comment: @TarasKumpanenko Not in *all* cases (see [How can val() return Number?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9227362/1715579))

Comment: @p.s.w.g but definitely in this case

Comment: We don't know since the OP did not include any markup.

Comment: @p.s.w.g. I`m agree, not always. Just make a suggestion $('#ATTN')- simple input[type=text]

Comment: We know because we're told that no alert occurs. OK, technically all we know is that it's not a number, so it could in theory be an array, but still.

Comment: @ChrisLear The question is unclear, we're only told it "returns nothing", which would certainly be true since there's no `return` statement. In my opinion, OP *really* needs to clarify and add sufficient context to fully answer the question—ideally with a snippet or jsfiddle that reproduces the behavior.

Comment: @p.s.w.g I think that "no error shown" means that the `alert` doesn't trigger. But I agree with your general point.

Answer (score 1):

This line

```
iattn=$('#ATTN').val();
```

Returns a string.

If you want to see whether it can be converted to an integer, then what you want is this:

```
iattn=parseInt($('#ATTN').val());
if (iattn) {
    alert("oh");
}
```

Use `parseFloat` rather than `parseInt` if you want a more general number test.

If you want to check that the result of parsing matches the input, use something like this:

```
iattn=$('#ATTN').val();
if (iattn == parseInt(iattn)) {
    alert("oh");
}
```

A simpler check, which won't actually convert anything to a number, and will allow all number formats (eg 2.3, 0x3, +23) is this:

```
if (!isNaN(iattn)) {
    alert("oh");
}
```

Credit to @p.s.w.g from a comment.

Comment: but chances are there the user give a text value by mistake and parseint will convert that too to an integer . that will make mess !

Comment: If the user gives a text value that can't be converted to an integer, `iattn` will be `NaN` and the if condition will fail.

Comment: I've updated with a check that the parsed value is similar to the input, to deal with cases like "2sdfsdsdf". But then if the user enters eg "2.0" the check will fail.

Comment: I believe `if (!isNaN(iattn))` would be equivalent for all cases except the empty string (you could use `if (iattn && !isNaN(iattn))` if necessary).

Answer (score 0):

`.val()` return a `DOMString`(string)

so `typeof iattn` always will be a `string`

if you want the `typeof number` you need convert to `int`

using `parseInt(iattn)` or `parseFloat(iattn)`