# Multiple .appends with one click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

html:

```
<h1>Favorite Animal:</h1>
<input type='text'>
<button>Answer!</button>
<div id='ans'></div>
```

Javascript (jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('#ans').append('<h2>Bunny</h2>')
    })
})
```

Hey there. I was wondering. Can I make it so that when I type a number into the input[type='text'] and then have that number of "bunny" appear? (example: I type in 3, the word "bunny" appears 3 times).

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a simple loop:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    for (i = 0; i < $('input[type=text]').val(); i++) {
      $('#ans').append('<h2>Bunny</h2>')
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' />
<button>Answer!</button>
<div id='ans'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

No problem, just create an array with that many indices, and fill it

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('button').click(function() {
    var n   = +$('input').val();
    var arr = $.map(Array(n), function() {
      return $('<h2 />', {text : 'Bunny'});
    });

    $('#ans').empty().append(arr);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>
  Favorite Animal:
</h1>
<input type='text'>
<button>
Answer!
</button>
<div id='ans'>

</div>
```

Comment: Maybe it's worth mentioning that the `fill` method is not supported by all browsers(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: @SLePort - correct, `Array.fill` isn't supported in IE, but MDN has a polyfill

Comment: Fortunately, jQuery has a way around that

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can get the input typed by the user, convert it from a string to a number, check if it's a whole number between 1 and 1000 and use it in a for loop. Each time add the element in the for loop. Here are some examples [How can val() return Number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227268/how-can-val-return-number) you can use a slider to do this an use html attributes to make sure the number is as you expect it to be

Answer (score 0):

More efficiently you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button').click(function(){
        $('#ans').append('<h2>Bunny</h2>'.repeat($('input').val()))
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You may try for This:

 1. In JS part:


    $(document).ready(function() {
          $('button').click(function() {
            for (i = 0; i < $('input[type=text]').val(); i++) {
              $('#ans').append('<h2>Bunny</h2>')
            }
          })
        })

 2. in HTML part:

     <input type='text' />
    <button>Answer!</button>
    <div id='ans'></div>
```