# how to add integers in input type number?

Tags: javascript, html

```
<input id='inpa' type='number' value=1>
```

**js**

```
var inp = $('#inpa').val();

$('#btnext').click(function(){
    $('#inpa').val(inp + 1);
    $('#inpa').val(inp += 1); // also tried
});
```

in both cases result is `11`!

how can I get `2` ?

Comment: `$('#inpa').val(parseint(inp, 10) + 1);`

Comment: if you console.log `typeof(inp)` you will see that it is a string, so cast the `inp` to an integer and then do the +1

Comment: Reading the value of an input always gives you a string.  Always pass it through parseint, farsefloat, or even Number() if you expect a number

Comment: you can find your answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9227268/how-can-val-return-number

Comment: @bonaca you have already been answered to that question. input values are always strings. That how it is meant to work.

Comment: So what is then the purpose of `input type number`?

Comment: Restricting the user to type only numbers. Not related to Javascript type. Html and javascript are to different things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of HTML inputs are always strings. You need to ‘parse’ the number as an integer.

```
parseint(inp)
```

will understand whatever `inp` is as an integer, which you can now +1 and -1 from.

When you set the value of the tag, it will change it back to a string for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse them into numbers first:

```
var a = parseInt($('#inpa').val(), 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert string to number using `Number` or `parseInt`

```js
$('#btnext').click(function() {
  var inp = Number( $('#inpa').val() ); /* Need to be inside the function, so that will get the updated value every user click*/
  $('#inpa').val(inp + 1);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id='inpa' type='number' value=1>
<input type="button" id="btnext" value="btnext">
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code concatenates strings.

You need to convert each variable to a number by calling parseFloat() around each one.

```
$('#btnext').click(function(){
   var inp = $('#inpa').val();
    $('#inpa').val(parseInt(inp) + 1);
   // $('#inpa').val(inp += 1); // also tried
});
```